# SQL query to find the head to head match winning

Tags: mysql

I have the following MySQL DB tables, which describes the matches and the results in a soccer championchips:

[image: Tables structure and example]

These rows come from the following SQL query:

```
    Select *
From RisultatiFantaAllenatori
Where Giornata = 10
```

And:

```
 Select *
From Partite
Where Giornata = 10
```

I want to calculate the head to head standings between one player and the other ones, for all the championchips. The Matches will be repeated every 9 matchesdays (for example Player1 will play against Player2 on MatchDay #10 and on MatchDay #19).
This is something that I'm going to expect:

[image]

For get the Win for the Player, the condition is that Player.points > OtherPlayer.points. For example in MatchDay10 if Player1 has obtain 4 points and Player 2 has obtain 1 points, Player1 has 1 head to head win against Player2.
I hope to be clear as possibile. So my question is: Is possibile to obtain an SQL query for this scope ? If yes, what is it ? Thank you in advance for your reply.

**UPDATE**

The attribute name is FantaAllenatore and not FantaAllenatori in the table RisultatiFantaAllenatori. In all case, by this query, is possible to have all the distinct players of the championchips:

```
    Select Cognome as FantaAllenatore
From FantaAllenatori
```

Comment: How is SQL Server involved? (Don't tag products not used in the case...)

Comment: The DB I'm using is just use to store the data. This project I created is just on my own. Are you meaning something else ? The DB query will be executed under php pages. Are you meaning something else ?

Comment: I was just asking which database product you are using. MySQL is one product, and MS SQL Server another.

Comment: I don't see anywhere in this question where MS sql-server is mentioned.

Comment: In the first line I wrote that I'm using MySQL :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe something like the following should do the trick:

```
SELECT
    t1.G1 as Player,
    t1.G2 as OtherPlayer,
    SUM(CASE WHEN t2.Punteggio > t3.Punteggio THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as `Win for the Player`,
    SUM(CASE WHEN t2.Punteggio < t3.Punteggio THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as `Win for the OtherPlayer`
FROM
    Partite t1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN RisultatiFantaAllenatori t2 ON
        t1.G1 = t2.FantaAllenatori AND
        t1.Giornata = t2.Giornata
    LEFT OUTER JOIN RisultatiFantaAllenatori t3 ON
        t1.G2 = t3.FantaAllenatori AND
        t1.Giornata = t3.Giornata
GROUP BY t1.G1, t1.G2
```

The magic here is in the SUM(CASE...) bits where it compares the results of each player match up to determine who one. The other important part is joining in your second table twice so that we get the score for each player for each match.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I got this error: Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 't2.FantaAllenatori' in 'on clause'. What do you think is the problem ?

Comment: DO you have a column named `FantaAllenatori` on table `RisultatiFantaAllenatori`?

Comment: I made mistake about the name, which is singular. So the attribute name of RisultatiFantaAllenatori is FantaAllenatori. Now the SQL runs, but the results I obtain is not totally correct. The problem is that one player, can be G1 or G2 in the Partite tables. For example Player1 vs Player2 is a match, but Player3 as G1 can play against Player1. By the way how do you modify the result ? Here is the result of the SQL https://www.dropbox.com/s/dwhcacu1wcxubgs/Result.pdf?dl=0